# How to specify project language in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

One can manually select project language at Bitbucket or use .gitattributes at GitHub.

Is there a way to make GitLab assign a specific language to a project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitLab will adhere to the overrides specified in your .gitattributes file.  Currently, GitLab uses the [Linguist Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/github-linguist/versions/4.8.1). Without these overrides Linguist will deduce the main language used for a project by analysing the code within files in the project.

You can find out how the magic happens by referring to the [Repository#main_language](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/65e845bad9bfe987f301b1100ce8262e4b724ccc/app/models/repository.rb#L951-955) method within the [gitlab-ce](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce) project.